# Unable to get current value of drop-down from HTML form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Experiencing an element select issue with jQuery that I can't seem to get past.

I'm attempting to present users who select Hawaii or Alaska from a drop-down menu with a certain message. The only portion I'm having trouble with is getting the value from the drop-down. The form itself is unsubmitted and I'm trying to grab the newly selected state value from this drop-down when the user clicks a continue button on my page. For the sake of simplicity, I would be happy with just getting the value to show in the console.

Here is my jQuery that I'm is returning *undefined* in the console. I could work with returning the value or the title of the value. Either is fine.:

```
jQuery('#region_id option:selected').val();
```

And here is my full HTML drop-down menu:

```
<select defaultvalue="" id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="State/Province" class="validate-select required-entry" style="">
    <option value="">Please select region, state or province</option>
    <option title="Alabama" value="1">Alabama</option>
    <option title="Alaska" value="2">Alaska</option>
    <option title="Arizona" value="4">Arizona</option>
    <option title="Arkansas" value="5">Arkansas</option>
    <option title="California" value="12">California</option>
    <option title="Colorado" value="13">Colorado</option>
    <option title="Connecticut" value="14">Connecticut</option>
    <option title="Delaware" value="15">Delaware</option>
    <option title="District of Columbia" value="16">District of Columbia</option>
    <option title="Florida" value="18">Florida</option>
    <option title="Georgia" value="19">Georgia</option>
    <option title="Hawaii" value="21">Hawaii</option>
    <option title="Idaho" value="22">Idaho</option>
    <option title="Illinois" value="23">Illinois</option>
    <option title="Indiana" value="24">Indiana</option>
    <option title="Iowa" value="25">Iowa</option>
    <option title="Kansas" value="26">Kansas</option>
    <option title="Kentucky" value="27">Kentucky</option>
    <option title="Louisiana" value="28">Louisiana</option>
    <option title="Maine" value="29">Maine</option>
    <option title="Maryland" value="31">Maryland</option>
    <option title="Massachusetts" value="32">Massachusetts</option>
    <option title="Michigan" value="33">Michigan</option>
    <option title="Minnesota" value="34">Minnesota</option>
    <option title="Mississippi" value="35">Mississippi</option>
    <option title="Missouri" value="36">Missouri</option>
    <option title="Montana" value="37">Montana</option>
    <option title="Nebraska" value="38">Nebraska</option>
    <option title="Nevada" value="39">Nevada</option>
    <option title="New Hampshire" value="40">New Hampshire</option>
    <option title="New Jersey" value="41">New Jersey</option>
    <option title="New Mexico" value="42">New Mexico</option>
    <option title="New York" value="43">New York</option>
    <option title="North Carolina" value="44">North Carolina</option>
    <option title="North Dakota" value="45">North Dakota</option>
    <option title="Ohio" value="47">Ohio</option>
    <option title="Oklahoma" value="48">Oklahoma</option>
    <option title="Oregon" value="49">Oregon</option>
    <option title="Pennsylvania" value="51">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option title="Rhode Island" value="53">Rhode Island</option>
    <option title="South Carolina" value="54">South Carolina</option>
    <option title="South Dakota" value="55">South Dakota</option>
    <option title="Tennessee" value="56">Tennessee</option>
    <option title="Texas" value="57">Texas</option>
    <option title="Utah" value="58">Utah</option>
    <option title="Vermont" value="59">Vermont</option>
    <option title="Virginia" value="61">Virginia</option>
    <option title="Washington" value="62">Washington</option>
    <option title="West Virginia" value="63">West Virginia</option>
    <option title="Wisconsin" value="64">Wisconsin</option>
    <option title="Wyoming" value="65">Wyoming</option></select>
```

Any ideas?

NOTE: That select menu ends with a `</select>` but I can't get it to show.

Comment: The ID in your jQuery isn't the same as the ID in the HTML.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use `:` in the ID. `:` is used as the prefix for CSS modifiers and pseudo-selectors.

Comment: I agree, however it's default Magento code HTML/CSS. I have to work with it unfortunately for the client's site. What is the correct way to select that element with jQuery in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per docs

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

thus, you need to escape  meta-characters using `\\`

```
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').val();
```

or use attribute equals selector:

```
jQuery('[id="billing:region_id"]').val();
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you Milind Avantwar! I knew it had to be some form of complication with how I was selecting it. (I can accept an answer in 7 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Change the HTML to:

```
<select defaultvalue="" id="region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="State/Province" class="validate-select required-entry" style="">
```

so that the ID matches your selector and doesn't use the special `:` character. Also, you don't need `option:selected`, `jQuery("#region_id").val()` will get the selected value.

If you can't change the HTML for some reason, you need to use the correct ID in the jQuery:

```
jQuery("#billing\\:region_id").val();
```

You need to escape the `:` to prevent it from being treated as a modifier prefix. And you have to double the backslashes so that it will be seen literally by jQuery.